# English Equivalent Of 抓耳挠腮

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, image-identification

The Chinese term 抓耳挠腮 means something along the lines of: *scratching one's ears/cheeks/head in embarrassment* or *tweaking one's ears and scratching one's cheeks (as a sign of anxiety or delight)*.

Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- What English phrases fit the description?

Comment: Yeah, scratching your head (figuratively or literally) is generally considered as sign of puzzlement.  Stroking your chin is considered a sign of deep contemplation.  Placing your palm over your face might be considered a sign of embarrassment.  Tugging your earlobe has several different meanings.

Answer (score 3):

You already found the answer. It is ***scratching*** *(one's head, chin, neck etc.)*. There isn't a special phrase for that, it is just a gesture and part of body language.

Scratching can indicate different emotions or states of mind, depending on where you scratch and other accompanying gestures.  For example:

- Scratching back of your head with a sheepish smile can indicate embarrassment
- Scratching your chin/cheek and pouting can indicate anxiety and frustration. You might be dealing with a question also as your pictures show.

There can be many reasons also as the below picture suggests:

[image]

<sub>*Decoding Body Language / [slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/aoweiyang/decoding-body-language)*</sub>

---

Beside gestures, ***scratch one's head*** is an idiomatic phrase also:

> 1 *informal* Think hard in order to find a solution to something.
>
> 1.1 Feel or express bewilderment.
>
> [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scratch-one%27s-head)

Comment: I like this thing of putting pictures in the answer when there are pictures in the question, it's good stuff. 